# Why can't we create an RDD using Spark session

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

We see that,

```
Spark context available as 'sc'.
Spark session available as 'spark'.
```

I read spark session includes spark context, streaming context, hive context ...  If so, then why are we not able to create an rdd by using a spark session instead of a spark context.

```
scala> val a = sc.textFile("Sample.txt")
17/02/17 16:16:14 WARN util.SizeEstimator: Failed to check whether UseCompressedOops is set; assuming yes
a: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = Sample.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> val a = spark.textFile("Sample.txt")
<console>:23: error: value textFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
       val a = spark.textFile("Sample.txt")
```

As shown above, `sc.textFile` succeeds in creating an RDD but not `spark.textFile`.

Answer (score 10):

In Spark 2+, Spark Context is available via Spark Session, so all you need to do is:

```
spark.sparkContext().textFile(yourFileOrURL)
```

see the documentation on this access method [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#sparkContext()).

Note that in PySpark this would become:

```
spark.sparkContext.textFile(yourFileOrURL)
```

see the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=udf#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sparkContext).

Answer (score 8):

In earlier versions of spark, **spark context** was entry point for Spark. As RDD was main API, it was created and manipulated using context API’s.

For every other API,we needed to use different contexts.For streaming, we needed `StreamingContext`, for SQL `sqlContext` and for hive `HiveContext`.

But as `DataSet and Dataframe API’s` are becoming new standard API’s Spark need an entry point build for them. So in Spark 2.0, Spark have a new entry point for `DataSet and Dataframe API’s` called as **Spark Session**.

`SparkSession` is essentially combination of `SQLContext, HiveContext and future StreamingContext`.

All the API’s available on those contexts are available on spark session also. Spark session internally has a **spark context for actual computation**.

> sparkContext still contains the method which it had in previous
>   version .
>
> methods of sparkSession can be found [here](https://github.com/soniclavier/hadoop_datascience/blob/master/spark/src/main/scala/com/vishnu/spark/blog/supportfiles/spark_session_blog_commands)

Answer (score 1):

It can be created in the following way-

val a = spark.read.text("wc.txt")
This will create a dataframe,If you want to convert it to RDD then use-
a.rdd Please refer the link below,on dataset API-
http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/438089/notebooks/spark2.0/Dataset.html